# ¿Cómo puedo generar 4 ion-card con un color diferente cada uno?

Tags: angular, ionic

soy nuevo utilizando IONIC.
Estoy intentando crear el juego de simon, pero tengo un problema para empezar que es que estoy intentando generar 4 ion-card con un color distinto, pero no se en que puedo estar fallando para establecer un color a cada uno de estos.

Si alguno sabe la manera o cual es mi fallo, se lo agradecería, gracias.

Dejo el código que actualmente tengo:

```
    export class HomePage {

  colors = [
    {
      name: 'red',
      background: '#F30B0B',
      sonido: '',
      num: 0
    },
    {
      name: 'green',
      background: '#1BCA30',
      sonido: '',
      num: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'blue',
      background: '#1E65EA',
      sonido: '',
      num: 2
    },
    {
      name: 'yellow',
      background: '#E8EB10',
      sonido: '',
      num: 3
    }
  ];

  setColors(color) {

    let num = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);

      switch (num) {
        case 0:
          return color.background;
        case 1:
          return color.background;
        case 2:
          return color.background;
        case 3:
          return color.background;
      }

      return null;

    }

}
```

```
  <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let color of colors">
    <ion-card (click)="setColors(color)">
    </ion-card>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: Que version de ionic estas usando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas usando ionic 4 en tus en theme/variables agrega los colores

```
  .ion-color-red {
    --ion-color-base: #F30B0B;
    --ion-color-base-rgb: 30,185,80;
    --ion-color-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
    --ion-color-shade: #ce0b0b;
    --ion-color-tint: #ff0d0d;
  }

  .ion-color-green {
    --ion-color-base: #1BCA30;
    --ion-color-base-rgb: 30,185,80;
    --ion-color-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
    --ion-color-shade: #18ad29;
    --ion-color-tint: #22e739;
  }

  .ion-color-blue {
    --ion-color-base: #1E65EA;
    --ion-color-base-rgb: 30,185,80;
    --ion-color-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
    --ion-color-shade: #1c53b9;
    --ion-color-tint: #1e6dff;
  }

  .ion-color-yellow {
    --ion-color-base: #E8EB10;
    --ion-color-base-rgb: 30,185,80;
    --ion-color-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
    --ion-color-shade: #cccf11;
    --ion-color-tint: #f3f712;
  }
```

En tu componenete agregalo de esta forma

```
 <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let color of colors" >
    <ion-card [color]="color">
    </ion-card>
 </ion-col>
```

En el archivo ts.

```
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'];
```

Si quieres cambiar los colores lo puedes hacer desde la lista colors

Comment: Si, estoy utilizando ionic 4 y me sirvio mucho tu respuesta, ya tengo cada ion-card con su color correspondiente.
Gracias Juan Lozoya.